# Enum type fields in JPA Entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use Enums as a type of a field (column) in custom JPA entities? Here is an example:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class PaymentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer statusId;

    public PaymentStatuses getStatus() {
        return PaymentStatuses.valueOf(statusId);
    }

    public PaymentEntity setStatus(PaymentStatuses status) {
        statusId = status == null ? null : status.getId();
        return this;
    }
}

public enum PaymentStatuses {
    CREATED(1),
    COMPLETED(2),
    CANCELED(3);


    private Integer id;

    private PaymentStatuses(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public static PaymentStatuses valueOf(Integer id) {
        for (PaymentStatuses value : values())
            if (value.getId().equals(id))
                return value;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code above works fine, but approach with `statusId` and `getStatus` `setStatus` looks ugly a little bit.

I wanna use `PaymentStatuses` as a type of the field in my entity. Like this:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class PaymentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private PaymentStatuses status;
}
```

Tell me please, is it possible?

Comment: You can use @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)

Comment: @Klaimmore `ORDINAL` starts to `0`. It is not compatible with the id used (`1`, `2`, `3`) to represent the enum in DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` will not work because the `ORDINAL` mode starts to `0`.
So the 3 first values of the enum will be represented in DB with the `0`, `1` and `2` values.
while the `id` field in the enum to represent it in the DB goes from `1` to `3` :

```
CREATED(1),
COMPLETED(2),
CANCELED(3);
```

Besides, this way would correlate the order of elements defined in the enum with the way to represent them in database. Which not a good thing as enum values could be added/removed in the future.

A better way to address your issue is defining a [`javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) and using it with [`@Convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html).
So create a `AttributeConverter` implementation to indicate how to convert from the DB to the enum and the enum to the DB.
Then declare  a `PaymentStatuses status` in your entity and annotate it with `@Convert` by specifying the `AttributeConverter` implementation class.

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class PaymentEntity {
  ...
  @Convert(converter = PaymentStatusesConverter.class)
  private PaymentStatuses status;
  ...    
}

public class PaymentStatusesConverter  implements AttributeConverter<PaymentStatuses, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(PaymentStatuses status) {
        return status.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public PaymentStatuses convertToEntityAttribute(Integer status) {
         return PaymentStatuses.valueOf(status); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. All works fine. Spring data jpa find queries works fine too.

Comment: @Bohdan Petrenko Thanks for the feedback. You are welcome.

Comment: this is working fine while bringing the values from database. 
But while insert into database throws casting exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but when you save to the database it will persist the current index of the enum value (in your case 0 for CREATED, 1 for COMPLETED, etc.) which will give you trouble if you change the enum values. To avoid this you can use the `@Enumerated` annotation like:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class PaymentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) // There is also EnumType.STRING, or you can define a custom EnumType
    private PaymentStatuses status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` if you want your data to be stored in the db like the name of the Java enum name (`CREATED, COMPLETED, CANCELED`)